# A question on torsion subgroups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, abelian-groups

Let $M$ be an abelian group. Consider the torsion subgroup $M_{\text{tors}}$.

Now, suppose that we can find a homomorphism $n^{-1}:M\to M$ the is an inverse to the multiplication by $n$.

Is this sufficient to assure that $M_{\text{tors}}=0$ (i.e., that $M$ is torsion free)?

Answer (score 4):

If you just mean that multiplication by $n$ is invertible for some $n$ then the answer is no. For example, if $n$ and $m$ are relatively prime positive integers and $M=\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$  then the homomorphism $\phi_n:M\to M$ given by multiplication by $n$ is invertible.

On the other hand, if multiplication by $n$ is invertible for all $n$ then $M$ is torsion free. Indeed, if $x\in M_{tors}$ then $nx=0$ for some positive integer $n$, and if multiplication by $n$ is invertible this implies that $x=0$.